# SeekBar not functioning due to ListView positioning

Tags: android

I have emulated a Pixel 3, a Nexus 5X, and a Galaxy Tab A, all running Oreo. The SeekBar is only functioning on the Galaxy Tab A. When you drag the SeekBar, a Toast message with the corresponding "progress" made on the SeekBar appears. On the Pixel and the Nexus, it will not allow me to drag the SeekBar. Attempting to click further down the bar to jump to a later position does not work either. The following bit of code is the only thing going on in my application:

*UPDATE* : I've discovered removing the only other view element in my app, a listView, fixes the issue. I don't know why. If I place a listView too close under my SeekBar, it stops the SeekBar from functioning, but this is only a problem on certain emulators. If I'm running it on a large Tablet emulator i.e. the Galaxy Tab A, it functions fine. I've included XML file for clarification.

With the following XML, SeekBar works fine:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="497dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

However, this will stop the SeekBar from functioning:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="497dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: What happens if you don't add a listener at all?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hey thanks for the suggestion! I removed the listener and tested again, still the same problem. However, removing the listener gave me an idea...The only other element in my application is a listView I'd placed below the seekBar.  I removed the list view and sure enough the seekBar started working fine across all the emulators.  I don't know why, but for some reason, if the listView is positioned too closely to my seekBar, it's stopping the seekBar from functioning properly on certain emulators.  I

Comment: So the huge bottom margin might be pushing the list view to overlap the seek bar, since you haven't set any constraint between the two views. If your layout isnt much more complicated than this you probably want to be using LinearLayout anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 I worked it out with your suggestion, somewhat lol. I'm picking up mobile coming from a web background and so far I think understanding the different layout schemes and how they work has been the hardest part. Thanks again!